# SonarQube V4 plugin for VSTF 2017

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have just updated the SonarQube plugin to V4 in my VS2017 VNext build but the build is sat waiting for an available agent.

All my agents have MSBuild and Java, are there any other capabilities required for the V4 update.

If I move back to the V3 SonarQube plugin the same build works fines

Answer (score 2):

v4 of the tasks do not add any new demands. However, the new version is written in Node.js rather than PowerShell (so it can run on non-Windows build agents). If you are running an on-premise version of TFS you might need to update your build agents.

FYI when I ran the v4 of the task on TFS2017.2 the build failed with the message *No agent found in pool X which satisfies the specified demands: .... Agent.Version -gtVersion 2.119.1*

The Microsoft docs for upgrading the agents are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/agents/agents). I ended up downloading the specified version of the agent from the vsts-agents [releases](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/releases) page on GitHub.